# cURL POST command is unresponsive

Tags: java, docker, apache-kafka, cqrs, event-sourcing

I was learning about the `Event Sourcing and CQRS` and find a nice video series on Youtube. The series has a code repository given in the [Github](https://github.com/sdaschner/scalable-coffee-shop). It uses 3 modules (`barista`, `orders`, and `beans`) that talks with each other in the distributedly for managing Coffee orders from the customers. The run instruction is provided as follows,

> 1. Start Apache Kafka brokers, e.g. using Docker compose: https://github.com/wurstmeister/kafka-docker.
>      Configure the `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME` to your corresponding IP
>      address.
> 2. Configure each of the `kafka.properties` files with `bootstrap.servers=<your-IP>:9092`.
> 3. Build and run the individual instances. On each of the `orders/`, `beans/` and `barista/` directories, execute `build-run-local.sh`.
>      This builds the Gradle project, builds the Docker image and starts a
>      new instance of the given service.

I follow the steps seamlessly. After I build and run the individual instances, I execute the command,

```
$ curl http://localhost:8002/beans/resources/beans -i

    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Connection: keep-alive
    Content-Type: application/json
    Content-Length: 2
    Date: Tue, 08 Jan 2019 13:16:12 GMT
```

Then, I tried to POST a bean with the command,

```
$ curl http://localhost:8002/beans/resources/beans -i -XPOST \
      -H 'content-type: application/json' \
      -d '{"beanOrigin": "Colombia", "amount": 10}'
```

At this point, the terminal gets hanged and produce no response. I look into the individual modules and see the `Dockerfile` and the `build-run-local.sh` with execution instructions. For example, the `Dockerfile` for the `beans` module is provided below,

```
$ cat Dockerfile 

  FROM sdaschner/wildfly:javaee8-kafka-b1

  COPY build/libs/beans.war $DEPLOYMENT_DIR
```

The `beans/build-run-local.sh` is provided,

```
$ cat build-run-local.sh 

#!/bin/bash
cd ${0%/*}
set -eu

gradle build
docker build --rm -t scalable-coffee-shop-beans:1 .
docker run --rm --name beans -p 8002:8080 scalable-coffee-shop-beans:1
```

When I run the file I get output (initial lnes),

```
$ ./build-run-local.sh 

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 0s
5 actionable tasks: 5 up-to-date
Sending build context to Docker daemon  310.3kB

Step 1/2 : FROM sdaschner/wildfly:javaee8-kafka-b1
 ---> 7a638cd4a3c8

Step 2/2 : COPY build/libs/beans.war $DEPLOYMENT_DIR
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ef4901bbea66
Successfully built ef4901bbea66
Successfully tagged scalable-coffee-shop-beans:1
=========================================================================

  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: /opt/jboss/wildfly

  JAVA: /usr/lib/jvm/java/bin/java

  JAVA_OPTS:  -server -Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MetaspaceSize=96M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true
```

My suspicion is the POST command gets hanged because  I might need more configurations that I'm missing. For example, I haven't configured any of `$DEPLOYMENT_DIR`, `JBOSS_HOME` or `JAVA_OPTS` mentioned earlier.

I admit I have limited experience (or very little) experience with `Docker`. But, I find this is the command executes the info of the `Docker` file,

```
# get 2 instructions from the `Dockerfile` and excutes them. 
$ docker build --rm -t scalable-coffee-shop-beans:1 .

Sending build context to Docker daemon  310.3kB
Step 1/2 : FROM sdaschner/wildfly:javaee8-kafka-b1
 ---> 7a638cd4a3c8

Step 2/2 : COPY build/libs/beans.war $DEPLOYMENT_DIR
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ef4901bbea66
Successfully built ef4901bbea66
Successfully tagged scalable-coffee-shop-beans:1
```

Can anyone help me to run the app properly?

**Update:**

I followed the advice from the comment and put the log messages. What I get is:

```
03:26:12,271 INFO  [com.sebastian_daschner.scalable_coffee_shop.beans.boundary.BeansResource] (default task-1) Bean origin = Colombia , Amount = 10

03:26:12,273 INFO  [com.sebastian_daschner.scalable_coffee_shop.beans.boundary.BeanCommandService] (default task-1) Bean origin = Colombia , Amount = 1
```

So it seems that the `com.sebastian_daschner.scalable_coffee_shop.beans.boundary.BeanCommandService` did get the info properly and call the method of the class `com.sebastian_daschner.scalable_coffee_shop.events.control.EventProducer` as follows,

```
public void storeBeans(final String beanOrigin, final int amount) {


        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Bean origin = " + beanOrigin +
                " " + ", Amount = " + amount);
        eventProducer.publish(new BeansStored(beanOrigin, amount));
    }
```

Inside the `EventProducer`, it calls the `publish` method which is provided below,

```
public void publish(CoffeeEvent... events) {
        try {

            LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Events = " + Arrays.toString(events));

            producer.beginTransaction();
            send(events);
            producer.commitTransaction();
        } catch (ProducerFencedException e) {


            LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, e.toString(), e);
            producer.close();
        } catch (KafkaException e) {

            LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, e.toString(), e);
            producer.abortTransaction();
        }
    }
```

At this point, I dont get any log from the code,

```
LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Events = " + Arrays.toString(events));
```

I assume it's related to Kafka and the code below doesn't execute:

```
     producer.beginTransaction();
     send(events);
     producer.commitTransaction();
```

As I point it out exactly, does anyone can help now to find out what's wrong?

Comment: Without downloading the Github code ourselves, it's hard to tell where the issue is... Could be Kafka, or it could be the web server. I would suggest adding more logging statements, or enable remote debugging into these Java processes to find the problem

Comment: Do you real need to call `producer.beginTransaction()`,  `producer.commitTransaction()` ??

Comment: @cricket_007 I updated the question to provide better info for investigation.

Comment: Well, do you need Kafka Transactions? Is there really a need to send more than event at once?

Comment: But if you are not even starting to see `Arrays.toString(events)` logger, then the problem sounds like it is not Kafka

Comment: @cricket_007 yes, the goal is to create a scalable system with many customers, diff. bean types and barisits in the shop. So it required to send more than one event

Comment: I understand that, but do you need **transactions**? (Which are a new Kafka feature) Can't you just send and acknowledge each message individually?

Comment: @cricket_007 ehh, its if that log is not be seen, it mght not be Kafka. I need to begin than and update the question ... the code is not mine and I'm not an expert. I'm just learning at the moment.